# Was Michael Dorn (Worf) not allowed to fly during The Next Generation? If so, why?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, behind-the-scenes

On [Michael Dorn's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dorn#Personal_life), there's the sentence:

> A member of the Aircraft Owners and Pilots Association,<sup>*[9]*</sup> Dorn enjoys flying. He was not permitted to fly while on The Next Generation, but was able to do so after joining the cast of Deep Space Nine.<sup>*[citation needed]*</sup>

There's no source for this, and Google doesn't want to tell me. **Was he actually prohibited from flying during *The Next Generation*? If so, why?**

Comment: Who would have prohibited him from flying? The FAA? Paramount? Roddenberry? Patrick Stewart and a motley posse of anti-flying "enforcers"? Your mom?

Comment: @RobertColumbia - who knows? It could have been in his contract or something.

Comment: I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that the reason (if true) was "to prevent one of the show's most prominent actors from dying in a horrific plane crash".

Comment: @F1Krazy or maybe to prevent aliens from kidnapping him in order to get him to fly a replica of the Enterprise against a powerful enemy...

Comment: Personal annecdote: I had to agree to not take non-commercial flights when I signed up for my current life insurance policy (unless I purchased a separate rider each time I did so). And I'm not a principle actor on a popular tv show. Apparently it's sufficiently dangerous to warrant such treatment.

Comment: This is not unusual for people who work on projects that are insured and that could suffer losses or delays if they were to die or become injured. For example, [Arian Foster's NFL player contract](https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1573683/000104746913009713/a2216998zex-10_3.htm) prohibits him from "serving as a pilot or crew member on any flight".

Comment: @RobertColumbia : When Gurney Halleck and his motley posse of anti-flying "enforcers" go forth in his work, as a wild ass in the desert, prohibiting you from flying, you just. don't. fly.

Comment: @Jared Smith You mean you can't fly on NetJet or the other charter jet companies?  Horrors!

Comment: @ab2 actually, that I could do: those are 'commercial' flights. I just can't fly with an *amateur* (read: not regularly paid to fly) pilot.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

He was certainly allowed to fly during TNG, and did so regularly while on the show, moving up from a [Cessna prop aircraft to a CASA military jet trainer between season 5 and season 7 of TNG](http://airportjournals.com/michael-dorn-a-trek-worth-remembering/), then graduating to a (potentially) supersonic T-33 jet during the filming of the first season of DS9.

> **MD:** *It’s a dream come true. I was always a student of airplanes and aviation since I was a kid . What happened was that we had a
> writer’s strike after the first year of ‘Star Trek’ so we had five
> months off, and a guy I knew that was a pilot  said come on, we’ve got
> to do this . You’ve  got to go out there. I said you’re right. I went
> out there–took my introductory flight and I was hooked. Nobody could
> find me during the day because I was out at the airport flying. Then,
> to make a long story just a little bit longer, **during, I think,  the
> third or fourth season of ‘Star Trek’, one of the producers on ‘Cheers’
> called me and they said that Woody Harrelson was invited to fly out
> with the Blue Angels, but he couldn’t do it.  Do you want to go? So I
> flew out. They pulled me out there. I had a twin engine Cessna in
> between the F-18’s and parked it there.** Of course, I’m the coolest guy
> in the world, and so when I flew with them it was eye opening. I
> discovered that you could own these airplanes. So I started
> researching it , the rules and regulations and what’s available, and
> all these airplanes were available for pretty cheap. So, I took my
> time, learned how to fly, and I went through the same type of process
> the air force pilots go through. And got to the F-86 and it just kinda
> happened. It was amazing.*
>
> <sub><sup>[‘Star Trek’ actor Michael Dorn chats latest projects and flying jets](https://nerdalertnewsblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/star-trek-actor-michael-dorn-chats-latest-projects-and-flying-jets/)</sup></sub>

The version of the story I've read is that Dorn's contract for the first TNG ***film*** included a stipulation that he not fly as Pilot-in-Command (e.g. solo flight) during the principal filming, a pretty common contractual clause for movie actors with pilot's licenses or who take part in risky sports such as [rock-climbing](http://batman-news.com/2016/08/16/jared-leto-suicide-squad-contract/) or [football](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=pJpdDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=movie%20contract%20stipulations%20dangerous&source=bl&ots=tLE5JaDtf4&sig=eN0i9T4XWCxrRX5dK5DhwRnnct8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjnrrzD3-jVAhXPJlAKHamrDF0Q6AEISDAF#v=onepage&q=movie%20contract%20stipulations%20dangerous&f=false), etc.

Comment: So I guess jumping out of the plane would have been perfectly acceptable...

Comment: If it was on fire, yes.

Comment: @Machavity - Any landing you can walk away from is a good landing.

Comment: More like "It is a good day to die!"

Comment: @Machavity - Tell that to the insurance underwriter and watch their head explode.

Comment: So now somebody needs to edit the Wikipedia page...

Comment: @Mithrandir - You could spend a lifetime editing all the wrongness put of wikipedia

Comment: Would it be worth expanding on why this common clause exists, or should that be a question on its own elsewhere?

Comment: @WeckarE. [movies.se]

Comment: _Of course, I’m the coolest guy in the world, and so when I flew with them it was eye opening_ => what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @1252748  - He's saying that they tried to scare him with their acrobatic flying but that he just enjoyed it